# AngularJs - My ui-sref anchor tag can't be cancelled by event.preventDefault()

Tags: html, angularjs, preventdefault, ui-sref

I have this tag:

```
<a ui-sref="MyModule">My Module</a>
```

When I click on the link, this will be executed:

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event) {

        if (!confirm('You have unsaved changes, continue?')) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

But still my view will switch to MyModule interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this:-

```
$scope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event) {

        if (!confirm('You have unsaved changes, continue?')) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

You are using `UI-router`. which is state based.